# Why am I getting the "The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action" error when I try to post a video (but not a photo)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been successfully posting from my app to user's walls for a couple of years now using the methodology defined here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

and now I'm switching to posting video (instead of photos) to their walls and suddenly am getting this error:

{"error":{"message":"(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action","type":"OAuthException","code":200}}

Presumably the permissions for posting photos and videos are the same (as far as I can tell) so this is almost certainly a red herring error (not unusual for facebook).  So, I'm curious if anyone else uses the /post/ method to publish content to the walls of users who have authorized your apps and I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong... After I pull the user's access token (which I have xxxed out below) the rest of my call looks like this:

```
    post/access_token=xxxxxxxxx
&from=MyCompany
&to=user_facebook_id
&title=SomeString
&link=URL_TO_FOLLOW_BACK_FROM_FB
&source=URL_OF_VIDEO_FILE
&name=SOME_STRING
&type=video
&picture=URL_OF_THUMBNAIL
```

My guess is that I'm missing something in the call, but I can't figure out what it might be.

Comment: I'm guessing your app didn't ask for video posting permissions when the user did OAuth. You can specify which permissions during your OAuth process, or setup defaults on the application level. Don't have a link for you, but try searching video upload permissions

Comment: are you sure? all the info related to this seems to say that the only two permissions needed are "offline_access" and "publish_stream".  I can't find anything related to granular permissions such as "video_post" or anything like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is what is different:

> Video POST requests should use graph-video.facebook.com

Source: [Graph API > Video](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/video/)